# Conan: How to access package id hash or generate it in build step of conanfile.py?

Tags: conan

How to access or generate package id hash in conan in the build step of conanfile.py?
I want to pass it inside cmake to report on -v the full version of my program including the hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known question in Conan Issues, please take a look there: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/7100

Basically, you can access it by:

```
packageid = self.info.package_id()
```

Comment: ERROR: conanfile.py (proxy/0.0.8): Error in build() method, line 23
        print(self.info.package_id())
        AttributeError: 'ProxyConan' object has no attribute 'info'


    def build(self):
        cmake = CMake(self, cmake_program="cmake3")
        pprint(vars(self))
        print(self.info.package_id())
        cmake.configure()
        cmake.build()

conan v 1.26.1

Comment: I can sure you it works: https://gist.github.com/uilianries/daf32f499b8b1fea224d98c501f2bdde You need to share your conan recipe to get more information.

Comment: It exists during conan create ., but it doesn't exist during conan build .
Not sure why

Comment: conan build skip some steps, conan create can't be compared to development flow, more info: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/5165